# Android: Google PlacePicker Widget How to prevent user choosing unknown location?

Tags: android, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I have added Google Places API and use a Place Picker Widget. Is it possible to prevent users to select unknown locations which are not available in Google places database ? Currently, the widget allow users to choose any point on the map including latlng not available in the places database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to prevent the user selecting a latlng and not a place in the Place Picker.